# I'm using the dot product of these two vectors but its not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, angle

I am using the dot product of the players position and the cursors position and then using the cosign of that value to rotate the player appropriately, but is glitching and acting very strangly, switching from negative to positive numbers seemingly randomly, and i cant seem to fix it.

```cs
camRotation = Mathf.Cos(player.transform.rotation.x + player.transform.rotation.y * Input.mousePosition.x + Input.mousePosition.y);
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, player.transform.rotation.z), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, camRotation * 100), 1 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: *"I am using the dot product"* are you? that doesn't seem to me to be how to calculate the dot product? Vectors also already have a dot product function, why not just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from your question, you are trying to spin the player based on the current mouse position. However, there are a couple of issues with your approach:

1. You should use `Quaternion.Slerp` rather than `Quaternion.Lerp`, as lerp simply interpolates each field and is almost never what you are looking for. Quaternion.Slerp moves as if spinning a sphere
2. Unnecessary cosine calculation - `Quaternion.Euler` takes an angle, so just using the mouse position as the angle should acheive the desired effect
3. Spinning on the wrong axis - you probably meant to use the y-axis rather than the z-axis

This is probably what you are looking for:

```cs
camRotation = Input.mousePosition.x;
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.Euler(0, player.transform.rotation.y, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, camRotation * 5, 0), 1 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Please comment if I have misinterpreted :)